# Is it possible to build libpqxx without SSL support

Tags: linux, openssl, vcpkg, libpqxx

I am having difficulty using `libpqxx` in my application due to a version conflict. `libpqxx` uses OpenSSL 3 and my application uses OpenSSL 1.1.1 and I can't upgrade from 1.1.1 to 3. I installed `libpqxx` using `vcpkg`, which brings in OpenSSL 3.

- Is it possible to build `libpqxx` without the SSL support in Linux?
- If `vcpkg` is not an option, can building from source remove the dependency to OpenSSL?
- If none of these work, is there any way to get an older version of `libpqxx` with OpenSSL 1.1.1 support?

Comment: libpqxx does not have a direct SSL dependency so all builds are "without SSL".    Pretty much the whole package is just a wrapper around libpq.  A quick read of that build system says you can build libpq if you exclude the "with_ssl" option described in the documentation.